# How can I pass the input and error of my failing task to a fallback task using AWS Step Functions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, error-handling, aws-step-functions

I'm trying to add some error handling to my step functions state machine and I've been having issues on a specific scenario, for example if I have a fail on a step I have a catch to send it to another function, but in that function I need to perform logic using the last step input data (the one that failed), however, I just receive an error, is there a way to pass the input data with the error as well?

```
Send Notification:
        Type: Task
        Resource: !GetAtt CommunicationSendCertifiedEmail.Arn
        Retry:
          - ErrorEquals:
            - TierOneError
            IntervalSeconds: 2
            MaxAttempts: 9
            BackoffRate: 1.5
          - ErrorEquals:
            - TierTwoError
            IntervalSeconds: 4
            MaxAttempts: 6
            BackoffRate: 1.5
          - ErrorEquals:
            - TierThreeError
            IntervalSeconds: 4
            MaxAttempts: 3
            BackoffRate: 2
          - ErrorEquals:
            - States.Timeout
            - States.Runtime
            - States.TaskFailed
            - Lambda.ServiceException
            IntervalSeconds: 4
            MaxAttempts: 3
            BackoffRate: 2
        Catch:
          - ErrorEquals:
            - States.ALL
            Next: Send Email Notification
```

on that "Send email notification" is where I need the input before the execution failed, but as I stated before I just get something like this:

```
{
  "Error": "Error",
  "Cause": "{\"errorType\":\"Error\",\"errorMessage\":...
}
```

I would like to get something like this:

```
{
  "data": "{...}",
  "Error": "Error",
  "Cause": "{\"errorType\":\"Error\",\"errorMessage\":...
}
```

Any ideas? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Use [`ResultPath`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-resultpath.html) in a `Catch` to include the error with the original input, instead of replacing it.**

> ResultPath (Optional)
>
> A path that determines what input is sent to the state specified in the Next field.

---

**[If you don't specify the `ResultPath` field, it defaults to `$`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-resultpath.html)**.

This selects and overwrites the *entire* input to replace it with the state output (which is an error in this case), which is why you're not getting any input data coming through.

Here's an example - **this is not what you want but is what is currently happening**:

[image]

---

**Specify a `ResultPath` for where the error output should go.**

That way, it'll take the state output (which is an error in this case) and *includes* it with the input.

This won't overwrite all of the state input, which allows you to preserve the input.

Here's an example - **this is what you want**:

[image]

---

Try:

```
Catch:
  - ErrorEquals:
    - States.ALL
    Next: Send Email Notification
    ResultPath: $.error
```

If the previous `Catch` statement catches an error, it'll include the error output in an `error` node *within* the state input (the node is called `error` as we specified the path to be `$.error`).

This acts like the second figure above.

---

For example, if the state input for *Send Notification* is:

```
{
    "foo": "bar"
}
```

The state output that is sent to *Send Email Notification*, when catching an error, will be the following.

```
{
  "foo": "bar",
  "error": {
    "Error": "Error here"
  }
}
```

It may also be the below, as the object also usually contains the `Cause` field (as it does in your case). This field's value is a human-readable description of the error.

```
{
  "foo": "bar",
  "error": {
    "Error": "Error here",
    "Cause": "{\"errorType\":\"Error\",\"errorMessage\"
  }
}
```

---

**Important note:**

Choose a unique name for the `error` node depending on your input data as I've just used `error` for demonstration purposes.

If the node specified already exists e.g. you already have a field with the name `error`, the `ResultPath` will *update* & overwrites the node with your error output which isn't what you want.

A picture is worth a thousand words, so this is the 3rd path that is possible using a `ResultPath` (again, **this is not what you want**):

[image]

---

If you're curious, the last path possible (which isn't related to the question but good to know) is discarding the state result (which you need, hence why it isn't related) and keeping the original input.

Setting `ResultPath` to `null` achieves this, as outlined [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-resultpath.html#input-output-resultpath-null).

Comment: Thanks for your answer and super detailed explanation!

Comment: @JorgeRodríguez You’re welcome!

Comment: @JorgeRodríguez Just to make sure - does the `Cause` field also get included in the error object in the same way I’ve mentioned? That’s the only bit I’m not 100% on

Comment: NOTE!!! States.All will not catch all errors! there are others like Lambda.Unknown (which is a timeout error usually, though could sometimes be thrown for another) and, I dont have access to my works definition at the moment, but pretty sure will not catch Custom Exceptions.

Comment: @lynkfox Actually, `Lambda.Unknown` **is** caught by `States.All` - [Unhandled errors in Lambda are reported as Lambda.Unknown in the error output. These include out-of-memory errors and function timeouts. You can match on Lambda.Unknown, States.ALL, or States.TaskFailed to handle these errors.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-error-handling.html)

Comment: In practice, i find this is not the case. Specifically, my projects state machine was not catching Lambda.Unknown errors if an api call inside the lambda waited longer than the lambda timeout. The state machine would report this as Lambda.Unknown - but our catch would not pick it up until I specifically added a catch for Lambda.Unknown. I do not know why this is the case, as I read that documentation too while building the state machine and was confused when it didnt catch.

Comment: It really depends on how many catches you have etc. but another conversation for another day!

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary yes it includes the cause