# How to pass output of one action as an input to another action in state machine Step functions?

Tags: aws-lambda, error-handling, aws-step-functions

I have an architecture where I want an output of one lambda function as an input to another in a single state machine. Also after I invoke all the 3 lambdas I want the error of each of them in Error Handling lambda.
How is this achievable in step function?

[image]

Comment: For the first part, refer to my answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/69544833/4800344

Answer (score 0):

The first part of your question is the very basis of State Machines. This would be done in a Parallel Task if you need them done simultaneously - if not you can simply chain them.  You should follow the documentation. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/welcome.html

As for the second part:

If they are **all** actually erroring? No its not possible to catch all three errors in the state machine - only the first would be caught using a catch - as soon as one lambda errors the state machine will stop its execution. If you are interested in catching the error that caused your state machine to fail (ie it should not be a normal scenario) then you can use the Catch properties of the State Machine Definition.

Again, refer to the documentation for how to code this.