# How can I access preceding state inputs using AWS Step Functions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions, serverless-framework-step-functions

Here is my step function:

```json
{
  "Comment": "A description of my state machine",
  "StartAt": "lambda1",
  "States": {
    "lambda1": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
      "OutputPath": "$.Payload",
      "Parameters": {
        "Payload.$": "$"
      },
      "Next": "lambda2"
    },
    "lambda2": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
      "OutputPath": "$.Payload",
      "Parameters": {
        "Payload.$": {
          "item_id.$": "$.item_id" 
        }
      },
      "Next": "lambda3"
    },
    "lambda3": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
      "OutputPath": "$.Payload",
      "Parameters": {
        "Payload.$": {
          "item_id.$": "" <------- How to access the id here
          "data.$": $.data
        }
      },
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

I am passing an `item_id` to `lambda2`, and that lambda returns some output data.

In `lambda3`, I need the output data of `lambda2` as well as the `item_id` that was passed to `lambda2` from `lambda1`.

I cannot modify the application code for `lambda2` to also return the `item_id` passed to it.

Is it possible for me to pass the `item_id` from `lambda1` all the way to `lambda3`?

Comment: Can you provide the output of Lambda 1 & the output of Lambda 2 please?

Comment: It will be like, Lambda 1 output - { status_code: 200, item_id: '1234' } and Lambda 2 output - { status_code: 200, data: {<some object>} }

Answer (score 1):

> In `lambda3`, I need the output data of `lambda2` as well as the `item_id` that was passed to `lambda2` from `lambda1`.

Yes, this is possible using `ResultPath`.

I've detailed the various outcomes of using `ResultPath` in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69544833/4800344).

In your case, you need a `ResultPath` of `$.DataFromLambda1` set for `lambda2` which would set the state input of `lambda3` to:

1. the state *input* of `lambda1` (which is the `item_id`)
2. + the state *output* of `lambda2`.

```json
"lambda2": {
  ...
  "OutputPath": "$.Payload",
  "ResultPath": "$.DataFromLambda1",
  "Parameters": {
    "Payload.$": {
      "item_id.$": "$.item_id" 
    }
  },
  "Next": "lambda3"
}
```

Then change `lambda3` to:

```json
"lambda3": {
  "Type": "Task",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
  "OutputPath": "$.Payload",
  "Parameters": {
    "Payload.$": {
      "item_id.$": "$.DataFromLambda1.item_id"
      "data.$": $.data
    }
  },
  "End": true
}
```